# Search classname in HTML string using python-3

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a string which is basically HTMl.

```
<div toast-component="" class="toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut ng-animating" style="">
   <button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c31-17 ng-star-inserted" style="">
   <span class="ng-tns-c31-17" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
   <div class="toast-title ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Success!" style=""> Success! </div>
   <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Data Successfully submitted" style=""> Data Successfully submitted </div>
</div>
```

I want to know that if this contains `toast-success` class. I am very new to python. Need some help. Basically I am using robotframework for automation testing

EDIT: My scenerio is that I got this string from Robotframework. I want to know that whether this div has `toast-success` class or `toast-error` class, so that I can proceed further. Not sure whether selenium has that capabilities. I am very new to this. Learning Automation testing now.

Comment: Add the code you tried with, and what problems you are facing. As given, the question is of little value, an answer could be "assert the class is in the string with Should Contain" - no python needed, and - no reusability. **Disclaimer**: don't just use that "answer", this is html, there can be false positives.

Comment: You had an other question about getting the innerHTML, now further processing it. I suspect that you have a problem that could be solved by selenium library itself, so please share your final goal as well.

Comment: @BenceKaulics, plz see EDIT. I also started learning Python too. Just want to know whether python can parse html sting like jquery.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `robotframework`, but if you're sure about how the `string` is presented then `if 'toast-success' in my_string` should do it, otherwise, you'll be better using something like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`.